# Из-за чего возникает ошибка?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, ругаться будет и на остальные data.title, data.lng и т.д
При чем всё работает как надо, но ошибка мозолит глаза

```
function place(){

    map.setZoom(5);

    var selectedOption = $('#objects_category').find(":selected").val();

    var data_id = eval(`markers_${selectedOption}`);

    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(data_id[0].lat, data_id[0].lng));


     var i = 0;
     var interval = setInterval(function() {

       var data = data_id[i];

      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

      // initial icon
      var defaultMarkerColor = '999';
      var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + defaultMarkerColor);

      // marker object for the marker
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: data.title,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: pinImage
      });

      // store in a global array
      var markerIndex = markerObjects.push(marker) - 1;

      // click listener on a marker itself
      google.maps.event.addListener(markerObjects[markerIndex], 'click', function() {
        var marker = this;

      });

      // create a row in the overlay table and bind onhover
      var $row = $('<li>')
        .addClass('list-group-item')
        .html(data.title)
        .on('mouseenter', function() {
          var marker = markerObjects[markerIndex];

        })
        .on('mouseleave', function() {
          var marker = markerObjects[markerIndex];

        });

      // create colorpicker and append to row
      $cp_div = $('<a href="#" ></a>');



      $row.appendTo('#overlay');

      // continue iteration
      i++;
      if (i ==data.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Вангую, что в `var data = data_id[i];` у `data` значение `undefined`

Comment: во что должно разворачиваться это: `var data_id = eval(`markers_${selectedOption}`);`? зачем тут eval?

Comment: eval тут, чтобы присвоить массиву markers_ номер выбранного массива, номер храниться в selectedOption

Comment: почему i используется как индекс для `data_id`, а границы его проверяются `i ==data.length`?